# Will Postgresql statements execute synchronously if autocommit=true?

Tags: postgresql-9.6, concurrency, database-internals, auto-commit

If a single application thread sends a series of `INSERT` statements and `autocommit=true`, will the statements be executed synchronously on the server?

I read that on the postgres server side, "there is one client process connected to exactly one server process",  but haven't found much more beyond that. I need synchronous execution to satisfy foreign key relationships, but I suspect the server (9.6) may run the statements concurrently.

Comment: A single connection can never run more than one statement at a time, regardless of the autocommit setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With autocommit enabled each statement forms a separate transaction. In a single session (connection) only one transaction can be active at a time. However, transactions in multiple concurrent sessions can, and will run simultaneously. In other words, as long as you issue your `insert` statements using the same database connection they will execute serially.

Whether you do that in a single application thread or not is irrelevant, since it's possible to open multiple database connections in a single thread, as it is possible to reuse the same connection between multiple threads (with proper synchronization, of course).